# SQL Server type to generate Instant in Mybatis Generator

Tags: sql-server, datetime, mybatis, jsr310, mybatis-generator

I want to define columns in SQL Server in order for Mybatis Generator to generate `java.time.Instant` or `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. According to [Mybatis Generator Core](https://mybatis.org/generator/configreference/javaTypeResolver.html), columns with type `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE` are mapped to `OffsetDateTime` when `useJSR310Types` is `true`

I used type [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in my DDL but my entities were translated as `Object`. Of course using [`DATETIME2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) results in `LocalDateTime`, which is not what I want.

Example DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserId        Int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    UserFirstName Nvarchar(50)       NOT NULL,
    UserLastName  Nvarchar(50)       NOT NULL,
    UserEmail     Nvarchar(100)      NOT NULL,
    Created DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Creator INT NOT NULL,
    Modified DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Modifier INT NOT NULL
);
```

Relevant fragments of `generatorConfig.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "https://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">
<generatorConfiguration>

    <contexttargetRuntime="MyBatis3DynamicSql" defaultModelType="hierarchical">
        <commentGenerator>
            <property name="suppressDate" value="true"/>
            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true"/>
        </commentGenerator>

        <jdbcConnection driverClass="${jdbcDriverClass}"
                        connectionURL="${jdbcUrl}"
                        userId="${jdbcUsername}"
                        password="${jdbcPassword}"
        >
            <property name="nullCatalogMeansCurrent" value="true"/>
        </jdbcConnection>

        <javaTypeResolver type="org.mybatis.generator.internal.types.JavaTypeResolverDefaultImpl">
            <property name="useJSR310Types" value="true"/>
        </javaTypeResolver>

        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage=""
                            targetProject="${workingDir}/src/main/java"/>

        <javaClientGenerator targetPackage=""
                             targetProject="${workingDir}/src/main/java" type="ANNOTATEDMAPPER"/>

        
        <table tableName="Users" domainObjectName="User" mapperName="UserBaseMapper">
            <property name="rootInterface" value=""/>
            <generatedKey column="UserId" identity="true" sqlStatement="JDBC"/>
        </table>

    </context>

</generatorConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another way.

Suggest Mybatis to use Instant

```
     <table tableName="Users" domainObjectName="User" mapperName="UserBaseMapper">
        <property name="rootInterface" value=""/>
        <generatedKey column="UserId" identity="true" sqlStatement="JDBC"/>
        <columnOverride column="Created" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE" javaType="java.time.Instant"/>
        <columnOverride column="Modified" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE" javaType="java.time.Instant"/>
    </table>
```

Maybe (maybe) the JDBC type is redundant, but it damn worked both on SQL Server and H2 DB, where H2 uses `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as column type

Comment: Note that `java.time.OffsetDateTime` is supported by [many DB/drivers](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1368#issuecomment-428922657) while `java.time.Instant` is not. So, MyBatis' built-in `InstantTypeHandler` has to convert `Instant` from/to `Timestamp` which could generate unexpected result depending on the value and the default time zone.

Answer (score 2):

MyBatis Generator is depending on the JDBC driver for type resolution. You can see how SQL Server does type mapping here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15

According to that page, `DATETIMEOFFSET` is mapped to a non-standard JDBC type `microsoft.sql.Types.DATETIMEOFFSET`. The generator doesn't know anything about that type (and neither does MyBatis itself). This is why the generator resolves the column to `Object`.

If you want to use `DATETIMEOFFSET` columns in SQL Server then you can use an override in the generator to map the Java type to `microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset`. You will also need to write a type handler so MyBatis can work with this type.

Unfortunately it looks like SQL Server does not have a type that maps directly to `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`.